# Where does the flat world start to corrupt?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have a LAN world where my friends and I are making a country. I also have plans making the surrounding ocean once we setted up the full land, but since Bedrock Edition doesn't currently have a WorldEdit sandbox or something, I can't really make it.

But my problem revolves around flat worlds (or infinite ones), because I wanted to set up something as a whiteboard, but I tried typing `/tp @s 3000000 -3000000`, the world has been reduced to only the top of the Grass Blocks, formatted like a chessboard, and can be fallen through. I was lucky enough to transfer back to the country.

Curious how I should max out the size of the country, where does the world start to have strange effects? I went to `x = 1000000, z = 1000000` before and nothing wrong is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It appears your game is glitching,** as flat worlds should be unable to be glitched drastically like that, while normal infinite worlds can. Additionally, Bedrock’s Graphics Engine begins to fail at certain distances, which is the main cause of the problem. According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Bedrock_Edition_Far_Lands):

> Far Lands do not generate on flat worlds, due to the lack of a noise
> generator.

Normal worlds get corrupted because they are generated with something called *Perlin Noise*, which is often used to give a randomized, rough texture to what it is used in. But, after around roughly 12,550,000 blocks, the procedural generation becomes corrupted, as the number becomes too large for the game to handle.

Comment: This is completely wrong.

Comment: many other things are using floating point, and the checkerboard pattern is common even in flat worlds, the hitbox bug with falling through the world is well known

Comment: i told you that OKprogrammer, i said something like "thats normal behavior its called the stripe lands"